# Android Bluetooth Low Energy Callback(LeScanCallBack) on seperate thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, callback

I'm starting the Bluetooth Low Energy Scan in the MainActivity:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        BLEScanner.start(bluetoothManager.getAdapter());
    }
}
```

The (static) BLEScanner class is as follows:

```
public class BLEScanner {    
    public static void start(final BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter) {
        bluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
    }

    private static BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                    String name = device.getName();
                    String address = device.getAddress();
                    Log.d("BLESCANNER", name+" "+address);
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            };
}
```

The Thread.sleep() in BLEScanner causes the UIThread to be unresponsive. How can i run the BLEScanner class in a seperate class?

Answer (score 0):

```
private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
        new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, final int rssi, byte[] scanRecord) {
                new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //The code here is executed on on new thread everytime 
                        Log.e("LeScanCallback", Thread.currentThread().getName());//Prints Thread-xxxx
                    }
                }).start();
            }
        };
```